# Python new variable in each iteration of for loop

Tags: python

I'm completely new at coding in general and was just messing around with lists and I was wondering if there was a way to make a loop go through every element of a list and run it independently of one another.
I guess an example would be like:

Input:

```
List1 = [ "a" , "b" , "c" , "d" , "e" ]
```

Output:

```
List2 = [ "a123" , "b123" , "c123" , "d123" , "e123" ]
```

Comment: Look in the python tutorial for list comprehensions and for loops

Comment: I don't think the question is "too broad", but it is unbearably lazy.

Answer (score 2):

This is what you are looking for:

```
list2 = [item + '123' for item in list1]
```

More on list comprehensions [here](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)

Answer (score 1):

```
List_One = [ "a" , "b" , "c" , "d" , "e" ]
TrailingNumbers = 3
for index in range(0, len(List_One)):
    for num in range(0,TrailingNumbers+1):
        List_One[index] = List_One[index] + str(num)
print(List_One)
```

This will modify the existing List obviously, didn't see the point in creating a new list, but if you do simply do:

```
List_Two = []
...
List_Two.append(List_One[index] + str(num))
```

I also assumed that you didn't have a fixed number to add after each letter.
For instance this would be a dynamical way to add numbers after each letter.

```
List_One = [ "a" , "b" , "c" , "d" , "e" ]
List_Two = []
TrailingNumbers = 3
for obj in List_One:
    List_Two.append(obj + ''.join(list(str(num) for num in range(0,TrailingNumbers+1))))
print(List_Two)
```

This is another way of doing it where you only use one loop to iterate over the first list, adding to a second list with a generator object for adding the numbers to your string.

A better approach to the first solution is to not count the index yourself and let `enumerate()` do the job for you. A bit quicker and considered "best practice", it goes something like:

```
List_One = [ "a" , "b" , "c" , "d" , "e" ]
TrailingNumbers = 3
for index, obj in enumerate(List_One):
    for num in range(0,TrailingNumbers+1):
        List_One[index] = List_One[index] + str(num)
print(List_One)
```

It will be a bit quicker, but will do the same job.

Comment: @sudo_O Except when you need the index to modify data while iterating over the object. Unless you use `list()` but then again you'd still need the index number for the object you're modifying. This is instead of using `.index()` each iteration.

Comment: using `enumerate` is the idiomatic way to achive this, sudo_O comment is right, using range is frowned upon (as well modifying the list while iterating over it).

Comment: @PauloScardine well true, `enumerate()` would work and do the job just as good. Seeing how this guy knows little to nothing about Python i simply wrote what enumerate did to better understand why things are happening. Lists are accessed by indexes, enumerate does exactly the above but gives you the index for each iteration. At least this way you'll be able to see what's happening and why it is happening and also how to use the index in order to access the objects you need?

Comment: I see you have good intentions, but I can't help myself, I'm such a syntax nazy. :-)

Comment: With the slight exception that `enumerate()` doesn't get the length of the list before iterating over it tho, if we're picky. `enumerate()` will simply do a `for obj in list: counter += 1 ...`

Comment: This is a good thing about enumerate; if the object is lazy evaluated like a generator, you can avoid lots of potentially expensive cycles if you break the loop. `enumerate` is the equivalent of `def enumerate(iterable): yield counter + 1, iterable.next()`

Comment: Yepp i couldn't agree more, so added it into the mix. Kept the original answer (again, for teaching purposes only..)

Answer (score 1):

```
list2 = [element + '123' for element in list1]
```

Answer (score 0):

A functional way:

```
List1 = [ "a" , "b" , "c" , "d" , "e" ]
map(lambda x: x+'123',List1)
```